# Problems creating a GIT worktree

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have a GIT repository which I would like to create a worktree from.  The repository looks like:

```
alpha
  .git
  Part a
  Part b
```

I execute the command git `worktree add ../beta beta`  (beta is a branch in alpha).  I get:

```
beta
  .git
  alpha
    Part a
    Part b
```

I want the copy worktree to look like the original, only with branch beta checked out:

```
beta
  .git
  Part a
  Part b
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything you're doing wrong here. Do you have a [mcve] for others to test this out?

Comment: It could be that the alpha repository is broken.  It is the result of a clone and filter-repo from another repository.  Is there a something like a git-repair command?

Comment: The filter-repo command uses basic Git operations (specifically `git fast-import`) so it should never build a broken repo. There is a `git fsck`, which does a consistency check of a repository; there are "expected failures" for this (dangling commits and blobs) but if anything really is entirely wrong, `git fsck` is *meant* to find that and point it out. So you can run that. A [mcve] would still be best though.

Answer (score 0):

> It could be that the alpha repository is broken.

As commented, [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) is the right tool to check if anything is amiss.

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2d019f46b00530c6c97413a840a4f0bb14b45877/Documentation/git-fsck.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck))</sup> learned to check the index files in other worktrees, just like "[`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2d019f46b00530c6c97413a840a4f0bb14b45877/Documentation/git-gc.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> honors them as anchoring points.

See [commit 8d3e7ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d3e7eac529b42319622692028b45670bdff8835) (26 Feb 2023), and [commit 592ec63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/592ec63b38ca7e2fb069ce1bf41b47a6f5a4ef8a), [commit fb64ca5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb64ca526a7c695aa137c2d2577585ddea5cce28), [commit 8840069](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8840069a37e69129ed3c2792ddb172557f98e205) (24 Feb 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2d019f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d019f46b00530c6c97413a840a4f0bb14b45877), 17 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/592ec63b38ca7e2fb069ce1bf41b47a6f5a4ef8a): mention file path for index errors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> If we encounter an error in an index file, we may say something like:
>
> ```
> error: 1234abcd: invalid sha1 pointer in resolve-undo
> ```
>
> But if you have multiple worktrees, each with its own index, it can be very helpful to know which file had the problem.
>
> So let's pass that path down through the various `index-fsck` functions and use it where appropriate.
> After this patch you should get something like:
>
> ```
> error: 1234abcd: invalid sha1 pointer in resolve-undo of .git/worktrees/wt/index
> ```
>
> That's a bit verbose, but since the point is that you shouldn't see this normally, we're better to err on the side of more details.
>
> I've also added the index filename to the name used by "`fsck --name-objects`", which will show up if we find the object to be missing, etc.
> This is bending the rules a little there, as the option claims to write names that can be fed to rev-parse.
> But there is no revision syntax to access the index of another worktree, so the best we can do is make up something that a human will probably understand.
>
> I did take care to retain the existing "`:file`" syntax for the current worktree.
> So the uglier output should kick in only when it's actually necessary.

---

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), this is clarified:

See [commit 6e6a529](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6a529b573398f0a8828551cf04dafb4f084c9a) (29 Jun 2023) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b00ec25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b00ec259e735fcb0dc4f697b7cc98b2730879d63), 08 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6a529b573398f0a8828551cf04dafb4f084c9a): avoid misleading variable name
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When reporting a problem, [`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6e6a529b573398f0a8828551cf04dafb4f084c9a/Documentation/git-fsck.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck))</sup> emits a message such as:
>
> ```
> missing blob 1234abcd (:file)
> ```
>
> However, this can be ambiguous when the problem is detected in the index of a worktree other than the one in which `git fsck` was invoked.
> To address this shortcoming, [592ec63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/592ec63b38ca7e2fb069ce1bf41b47a6f5a4ef8a) ("`fsck`: mention file path for index errors", 2023-02-24, Git v2.41.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d019f46b00530c6c97413a840a4f0bb14b45877) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e25cabbf6b34e4a6e903d65102d87055cc994778)) enhanced the output to mention the path of the index when the problem is detected in some other worktree:
>
> ```
> missing blob 1234abcd (.git/worktrees/wt/index:file)
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, the variable in `fsck_index()` which controls whether the index path should be shown is misleadingly named `"is_main_index"` which can be misunderstood as referring to the main worktree (i.e.
> the one housing the `.git/` repository) rather than to the current worktree (i.e. the one in which `git fsck` was invoked).
> Avoid such potential confusion by choosing a name more reflective of its actual purpose.